# OpenGL image load and store: bake screenspace texture into UV space texture

Tags: opengl

What i'd like to do:

I have a 3d transformed, uvmapped object with a white texture as well as a screenspace image.

I want to bake the screenspace image into the texture of the object, such that it's 3d transformed representation on screen exactly matches the screenspace image (so i want to project it onto the uv space).

I'd like to do this with image_load_and store. I imagine it as:

1st pass: render the transformed 3d objects uvcoordinates into a offscreen texture

2nd pass: render screensized quad, on each pixel, check the value of the texture rendered in the first pass, if there are valid texturecoordinates there, look up the screenspace image with the screenspace quad's own uv textures and write this texel color with image_load_and_store into a texturebuffer by using the uv textures read from the input texture as index.

As I never worked with this feature before, I'd just like to ask whether someone who worked with it already considers this feasible and whether there maybe are already some examples that do something in this direction?

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed way is certainly one method to do it, and actually it's quite common. The other way is to to a back projection from screen space to texture space. It's not that hard as it might sound at first. Basically for each triangle you have to find the transformation of the tangent space vectors (UV) on the models surface to their screen counterparts. In addition to that transform the triangle itself to find the boundaries of the screen space triangle in the picture. Then you invert that projection.